# How do I prevent a link inside an iframe from opening in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm new to Html and Javascript. I've been making an iframe browser with the help of an extension. [see my GitHub page](https://github.com/AzlanCoding/iframe-browser-pwa)
One of the issues my users face is that some links and redirects that occur in the iframe open in a new tab. How do I prevent this and allow the redirects and links(when clicked on) to open in the iframe? If not possible, is there a way to get the URL of the link before the page is redirected?

I tried adding `<base target="_self">`  in the head of the page.

Comment: Anyone can help me with this? I don't mean to be impatient but, I'm looking forward to an answer. I'm only 14 so I can't figure it out myself. Pls help.